# java on windows: read properties from file and pass them to java command

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

In a former version of our application, we used the Eclipse launcher on Windows for startup.  We hand the launcher an `.ini` file with java properties via the `--launcher.ini` property.

Now, we cannot use the launcher anymore and start the application from a `.bat` file using a `java -jar <file>` command.  Therefore, the properties in the `.ini` file have to be added to this `java` command individually.

My idea is to have the `.bat` script read the properties from the `.ini` file and store them in a variable as list.  The content of this variable is then used as part of the `java` command.  How to do that in a robust way?

Comment: Why not read the `.ini` from within your program? This way, you would be independent from the launching-method you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you start it via a *.bat script I would first check if the file exists using:

```
if not exist myfile.ini (
   # print some error
)
```

and if it exist I would iterate parse each line by:

```
FOR /F %i IN (myfile.ini) DO @echo %i
```

After that I would fill an array with the values and pass it to the java invocation.